# Angular: Understanding when to subscribe when submitting data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I'm getting really confused and wondered if anyone can help me try to understand .subscribe in angular 2 rxjs.

If i have a page with a button to submit some form data, do i need to subscribe in order to post information or use a promise?

As my understanding is when you subscribe, then you click the button again, you will then have 2 instances of the subscribe and so on. Now i know what your going to say, well you can kill the subscription in the destroy or whatever, but that isn't my question.

My question is, if the form is never destroyed until you clicked the home button and the form was clearing upon submit in order to submit some more data, do I need to use Promise over Subscribe? As subscribe (from what I understand) is like a newsletter, the more you click subscribe, the more occurrences of the newsletter you will receive.

So which is best to submit data over and over again, without having multiple subscriptions?

myObsFunc(dataToSend).subscribe(err => console.log(err), () => console.log(success));

or

myObsFunc(dataToSend).toPromise().then().catch(e => console.log(e));

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? What are you subscribing to on the button click?

Comment: Well, It's true, but you can always disable the buttons until you get a response for the current request or something similar if you don't want to end up with multiple result sets.

Comment: For a form you can use ngSubmit like:     <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFunction()">.  You don't need to subscribe or create a promise.

Comment: You need to use subscribe and unsubscribe only when you are handling Observables.

Comment: Oh okay so your saying if i'm making a post request to the backend, i just need to call my subscription but not subscribe eg: myObsFunction(dataToSend), rather then myObsFunction(dataToSend).subscribe()? but then how do i check whether it was successful or not?

Comment: I'm basically trying to store some data in the backend each time i click submit, so i have an observable function, but im trying to decide whether i should be subscribing to send the data or use or promise. as i need to check whether it was successful or not.

Comment: You need to subscribe to send the request. Calling toPromise() does subscribe. I prefer sticking to observables which are more powerful, but you can call toPromise() if you want. As soon as the observable complete or errors, i.e. as soon as the HTTP response comes back, you're automatically unsubscribed. So you shouldn't worry about unsubscrining from HTTP observables, which complete almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Observables are lazy
You could think of lazy observables as newsletters. For each subscriber a new newsletter is created. They are then only send to those people, and not to anyone else.

Observables can have multiple values over time
Now if you keep that subscription to the newsletter open, you will get a new one every once and a while. The sender decides when you get it but all you have to do is just wait until it comes straight into your inbox.

If you come from the world of promises this is a key difference as promises always return only one value. Another thing is that observables are cancelable. If you don’t want your newsletter anymore, you unsubscribe. With promises this is different, you can’t cancel a promise. If the promise is handed to you, the process that will produce that promise’s resolution is already underway, and you generally don’t have access to prevent that promise’s resolution from executing.

Comment: I get what your saying, but in the event of just doing a post, sending some data to the backend, how would i do that with an observable function? or is an observable the incorrect way of sending data in order to see whether or not it was successful? as i've got an application and my team members are subscribing to the observable on a page which just submits data over and over again, so in my mind we are creating subscriptions unnecessarily and there existing until i unsubscribe.

Comment: use take function of rjxs to unsubscribe immediately after you subscription job ends and use method of subscription

Answer (score 0):

Observable is stream data. Hope this code will help you to understand that.

```
import {timer} from "rxjs/observable/timer";

let observable = timer(1, 1000); //timer will emit an event each second

let subscribtion = observable.subscribe((data) => {
  //do stuff for each tick of stream data
  console.log(data);
}, (reason) => {
  //when there was an error while watching observable
}, () => {
  //do stuff when stream is complete
});

//when you need to unsubscribe from this events you can call
subscribtion.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I understand that concept, but in my scenario, is it best to subscribe in order to send data to the backend or use a promise? Bare in mind this subscribe function is on a button called submit, so if i called submit 3 times (without unsubscribing each time) i'll have 3 subscriptions correct?

Comment: Guys already told you that you do not need to subscribe when clicking a button. You need to make http call, which can be in component or better in some service. Then you need subscribe to service response. As for me http response (as we used to it) is one time subscribtion it is not a streem with number of events and it seems that promise in this case is better, but rxjs observable has number of operators(common operator for handling server side response is map). So it is better to use Observables everywhere in ng2/5 project, even it is one time event.

Comment: Post your code, so people will be able to understand your needs correctly.